# parse the contents of JSON data

Tags: flutter

I have an error in prase JSON data API flutter, 
the is the response from API

```
{
    "response": {
        "message": "Loaction Found",
        "responseCode": 0
    },
    "Loaction": {
        "driver_id": 1,
        "Latitude": "31.959727",
        "longitude": "35.837615",
        "time": "12/04/2020 16:09:33"
    }
}
```

I made the model from the https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

but I can't know how to prase the contents of JSON data, I try using the below code, but I didn't receive and data,
 can anyone help me ??

this is my all code:

https://github.com/mohmmed750/flutter-json/blob/master/json-flutter

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove this code

```
for (Map i in jsonData) {
  _list.add(DriverLocation.fromJson(i));
}
```

And use this code instead

```
_list.add(DriverLocation.fromJson(jsonData));
```

Then you can print in the console using, to see the list items.

```
for (var i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
   DriverLocation dl = _list[i];
   print(dl.loaction.driverId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse the json with DriverLocation class. You can straight off get the `Loaction` key from `jsonData` and parse it with `Loaction.fromJson()` directly.
Something like this:

```
var location = jsonData['Loaction'];
_list.add(Loaction.fromJson(location));
```

Code that I tried out - https://dartpad.dev/63fdc82ea0f6641698d42fcde47811f2

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but can I read the message into the response in JSON ??

Comment: Yes, you can. Just like how you are parsing `Loaction` key.